# Conditional pattern to be used along with required Angular7/8

Tags: html, angular, validation, ng-pattern, ng-required

In my template driven form the textarea is required based on a condtion. I would also like the pattern to be conditional. I tried this syntax based on a question from angular 1.x but it doesn't seem to work. - `pattern=" condition ? '.*[^ ].*' : ''"` I also tried - `pattern="condition ? (\s*[^\s]+\s*)+ : .*"`. is this possible with the later versions of Angular? Here is my stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/conditionalpattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to pass an expression, you should wrap pattern in square brackets. But more importantly, **you cannot use the attribute `pattern` in the tag `textarea`**, because `pattern` is not an allowed attribute for `textarea`.

As described in [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea),

> You can't provide specific regexs to validate the value against using the pattern attribute, like you can with the input element

So in your case I would either use an `input` or consider using a `CustomValidator`. If you use an input, make sure to wrap the expression in brackets:

```
<input type="text" [pattern]="condition ? pattern : noPattern">
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/conditionalpattern-hxlek8) a tiny stackblitz with a working example of an input field.

Comment: Thanks running some test now. I didn't realize pattern is not allowed in the text area

Comment: @Flash Happy to help. I added a stackblitz in case you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

u want to pass any expression ? try this:
<-input type="text" [pattern]="condition ? pattern : noPattern" >

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to use it for a texarea